# CSS question about positioning a play now button in the nav bar in the middle

Tags: css, reactjs, navbar

I am trying to move the button to the middle of the nav bar but having no luck. What element do I touch for CSS to do this?

[image]

This is my nav bar react js file trying to figure out what container to manipulate here.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import "./css/Navbar.css"
import { useNavigate , Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Metamask from "./Metamask"

function Navbar() {

  let navigate = useNavigate(); 
function clickHandle(){
  let path = `metamask`;
  navigate(path);
}

  return (
    <nav class="navbartop navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbarlabel navbar-brand " href="#">Souls</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      Nav Bar
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon navbar-dark"></span>
      </button>
      <button onClick={clickHandle} class="play-now btn btn-secondary btn-md">Play Now</button>    

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-list navbar-nav ">
          <li class="nav-item " >
            <Link to="/" class="nav-link-item nav-link " aria-current="page" href="Home">Home </Link>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar-list nav-item">
            <Link to="/whitepaper" class="nav-link-item nav-link" href="Whitepaper">Whitepaper </Link>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar-list nav-item">
          <Link to="/faq" class="nav-link-item nav-link" href="FAQ">FAQ </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Here is the nav bar css file added on here. I also wanted the button to be a link to another page but don't know the best way to do it.

```
.navbarlabel {
    color: white;
  
  }
  
  .nav-link-item {
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-around;
    color: white;
  
    
  }
  
  .navbar-toggler{
    color: white;
    border-color:white;
    
  
  }
  
  .navbar-toggler-icon{
    color: white;
  }
```

```css
.navbarlabel {
  color: white;
}

.nav-link-item {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbartop navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbarlabel navbar-brand " href="#">Souls</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      Nav Bar
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon navbar-dark"></span>
      </button>
    <button onClick={clickHandle} class="play-now btn btn-secondary btn-md">Play Now</button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-list navbar-nav ">
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <Link to="/" class="nav-link-item nav-link " aria-current="page" href="Home">Home </Link>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-list nav-item">
          <Link to="/whitepaper" class="nav-link-item nav-link" href="Whitepaper">Whitepaper </Link>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-list nav-item">
          <Link to="/faq" class="nav-link-item nav-link" href="FAQ">FAQ </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you show your Navbar.css?

Comment: Please see [ask]. Instead of stating that you have a question in your title, _ask the question_, clearly and specifically.

Comment: Also, this type of question isn't really related to React. If you can, post rendered HTML and your CSS in a demo snippet using the editor, so we can see the problem firsthand.

Comment: added css ty and ty it is a css question

Comment: I added a code snippet with your HTML and CSS. When you run it, you will find, that it doesn't resemble the image. So, there must be additional CSS not shown here.